# Increase/Decrease value in phpcassa

Tags: php, nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

Is there any method for simple increase/decrease integer value in cassandra using phpcassa? Maybe it is CounterColumn, but I didn't find anything about how to use it.

Basically, I just want to increase some counter on action, any tips or code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this [example](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/examples/counters.php). 
ColumnFamily::add() is the easiest way to increment a counter

`$count_cf->add("key1", "col1", 10);`